# ui-view: Slide animation without position: absolute

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to implement a slide in/out animation when transitioning between `ui-view`s.

[Here's a plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/LiptXAMbAxQCtJWkkP9b?p=preview) (Navigate from Home > About > Home)

When a new view appears, the old view jumps down below it. The intention is for the old view to seamlessly slide off left with no vertical movement, like a carousel.

I am aware of the `position: absolute` solution to this; but doing this rather messes up other elements of my layout; I'd like to keep the elements in the page flow. I have tried all manner of combinations of `display`, `position` etc.

```
  .slide-left {
    position: relative;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    margin: 1em;
  }
  .slide-left.ng-enter {
    transform: translateX(110%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .slide-left.ng-enter-active {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .slide-left.ng-leave {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .slide-left.ng-leave-active {
    transform: translateX(-110%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
```

Are there any other solutions? How do carousels work? (Off to check their source code...)

#### Edit:

Having checked Bootstrap's source code, they use `position: absolute` when the slide animation is in progress (`.next` and `.prev` classes). I'm concluding that the use of `absolute` is unavoidable for this effect to work; at least it only has to apply during the effect.

Comment: The code you provide works fine if you add ´overflow:hidden´ to the div wrapping your element (.container or add a new one) hopefully it doesn't mess with anything else in your code

Comment: Thanks for your thought, @Turqueso, but I don't think that makes a difference (not on Chrome, Firefox and Safari anyway). The exiting view still jumps down below the incoming view (visible if your browser window is tall enough - I want it to stay on the same level.

Comment: I misread your problem the first time, apologies. Reading again, I tried a few ideas but couldn't find one. Maybe it's worth think in refactoring?